# How to use next/image inside npm packege

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-images

I have next.js wrapper project around react ui library, which is included as npm package. Is there a way to use next/image for images optimization inside this React library?

I know that import next/image inside react project is not possible. So what is the approach to optimize images with next/image if images are inside another package?

Please, help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define Your own Image component and use it everywhere in your project, it might helpful!

```
import React from "react";

const Image = ({ src, ...props }) => {
 try {
  return React.createElement(require.resolve("next/image").default, {
   src: typeof src === "string" ? src : src.src,
   ...props
 });
 } catch {
  console.log("Not using Next.js");
  return React.createElement("img", { src, ...props });
 }
};

export default Image;
```

Use it like this (Please take this as an example)

```
import Image from "../utils/image";
import bg from "../assets/bg.jpg";

const Foo = () => <Image src={bg} height="640" width="959" />;

export default Foo;
```

Comment: How can i pass this Image component into another React child components?
I've tried to pass it down as a prop - `renderNextJSImage={(src, alt, layout, width, height) => <Image src={src} alt={alt} layout={layout} width={width} height={height}  />}`, and then calling renderNextJSImage();
but i'm getting an error that 'is not a function'

Comment: You have to import that component like same that i show you in above second part of answer.

Comment: I can't import like that, because Image component should be passed to the npm package. So basically i have next wrapper and react ui library thats included as npm package. So i need to pass this component as a prop somehow

Comment: Please try this once -> https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html
You can use props.children property.